# Meteor crashing "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to do a simple hello world in Meteor using React.js. When i try running the application it's crashing with "ReferenceError: document is not defined". This error doesn't make sense to me, how can document be undefined?

### client HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Testing 123</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

### Client Javascript

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    Meteor.startup(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
    });
```

### Full error log

```
C:\Users\Klynicol\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.4_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
                    throw(ex);
                    ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Client/main.js:18:28
at Function.time (c:\MeteorTut\meteortut\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:309:28)
at c:\MeteorTut\meteortut\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:312:13
at c:\MeteorTut\meteortut\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:353:5
at Function.run (c:\MeteorTut\meteortut\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
at c:\MeteorTut\meteortut\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:351:11
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try wrapping the render within ```Meteor.isClient``` ? eg.  ```Meteor.startup(() => {
        if(Meteor.isClient){
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
      }
    });```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your main.js is in Client with a capital C. Try renaming `Client` folder to `client`.

This would cause your code to be run server side where document is not defined.

Comment: Thanks, good catch. Seems like this may solve it, I'll try when I get home later :)

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling that this is happening because your code is trying to run in the server alongside the client. And since there is no `document` on the server, it's throwing an error.

This could be because of the client directory that you have. It's named as `Client` instead of `client`. I'm not entirely sure if the directory structures are case sensitive, but rename `Client` to `client` and have a go at it.

Ah! looks like @Damien Monni beat me to it...